# JLabel[][] array index out of bound error

Tags: java, arrays, exception, indexing

I'm getting an array index out of bound exception on the following code. I used debugger and this is what happened.

---

```
JLabel[][] labelHolder = new JLabel[8][8]; 

    for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        for(int j=0; i<8; j++){
            labelHolder[i][j] = new JLabel ();   <- error occur right on this line when i=j=0
```

---

I have not clue why this is because if I just swap out the i and j for 0 and 0, it work perfectly :S

Comment: Four duplicate answers...

Answer (score 4):

The condition in your second `for`-loop checks against the value of `i` instead of `j`

```
for(int j = 0; i < 8 ; j++)
```

should be

```
for(int j = 0; j < 8 ; j++)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
             ^
```

Answer (score 1):

`for(int j=0; i<8; j++){` This line has the problem, it should read `j<8`.

Answer (score 1):

In your second loop, your stop condition is mistaken: replace `i < 8` by `j < 8`.